# Ajax form submit mootools what am I doing wrong

Tags: ajax, forms, mootools

I have following js code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var trigger = $('sendme');
    trigger.addEvent( 'click', function(event){
          event.preventDefault()
          var sendform =    new Form.Request($('newform'), {
              onSend: function(){
                  console.log('sending');
              },
              onComplete: function(){
                  console.log('sent');
              }
          });           
          sendform.send();
    });
});
```

and form with data:

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_mycomp&amp;layout=edit&amp;id=1" method="post" name="newform" id="newform" class="form-validate">...
```

the form submits just fine and I can see changes but I get no logs, 
thus cant execute actions that I need

form action is not supposed to give me any response back , it is simple post but shouldn't this work? Do I need to send the form to another file that will give me responses like json and submit my form like that ?
what am I doing wrong ?

Any help is appreciated. Thnx!

**small update since post ,**

I change the form to send data and receive response via json file but still no response messages. everything is being updated so submit works 100%.

Comment: never mind!  was missing target , set target at console.log() and worked fine.

Comment: Feel free to write down your solution as an answer and mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right way is  new Form.Request($('newform'),**console.log(),**{

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var trigger = $('sendme');
    trigger.addEvent( 'click', function(event){
          event.preventDefault()
          var sendform =    new Form.Request($('newform'),console.log(), {
              onSend: function(){
                  console.log('sending');
              },
              onComplete: function(){
                  console.log('sent');
              }
          });           
          sendform.send();
    });
});
```